# canvas drawing size fix needed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

on my Canvas when you change size i have it soo you can go from 1 - 100 but i have it so it goes up in 5's but when you got to 1 and go up again it goes to 6 then up again and goes to 11 and so on.

here it is http://jsfiddle.net/daniel9000/tsaytohj/2/

here is my java script

```
function processData(c1, c2) {
var cv1 = document.getElementById(c1).value;
var cv2 = document.getElementById(c2).value;
alert(cv1 + "\n" + cv2);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 10;
var dragging = false;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

context.lineWidth = radius * 2;

var putPoint = function (e) {
if (dragging) {
var bounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var mouseX = e.clientX + bounds.left;
var mouseY = e.clientY - bounds.top;
var mouseX = e.clientX + bounds.left - 0;
context.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY)
context.strokeStyle = document.getElementById('color1').value;
context.stroke();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.fillStyle = document.getElementById('color1').value;
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
}
}

var engage = function (e) {
dragging = true;
putPoint(e);
}

var disengage = function () {
dragging = false;
context.beginPath();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', engage);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', putPoint);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', disengage);

var setRadius = function (newRadius) {
if (newRadius < minRad) newRadius = minRad;
else if (newRadius > maxRad) newRadius = maxRad;
radius = newRadius;
context.lineWidth = radius * 2;

radSpan.innerHTML = radius;
}

var minRad = 1,
maxRad = 100,
defaultRad = 20,
interval = 5,
radSpan = document.getElementById('radval'),
decRad = document.getElementById('decrad'),
incRad = document.getElementById('incrad');

decRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
setRadius(radius - interval);
});
incRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
setRadius(radius + interval);
});

setRadius(defaultRad);

var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
button.href = dataURL;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really pretty simple. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
decRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setRadius(radius - interval);
});
incRad.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setRadius(radius < interval ? interval : radius + interval);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have set minRad = 1, which is not in the sequence of multiples of 5, presumably to avoid having a radius of zero. So when you add 5 to it, you get 6 not 5. You have several possible solutions:

- set minRad = 0
- only allow a minimum radius of 5 i.e. minRad = 5
- if not either of the above, then you must compensate for using a minimum which is not in sequence, by replacing `radius = newRadius;` with:

  ```
  radius = newRadius;
  if( radius == 6) radius = 5;
  ```